# WebSocket com PHP utilizando servidor IIS 8.0

Tags: php, javascript, html, iis, websocket

Bom dia.

Seguinte, baixei o seguinte projeto como exemplo para criar um WebSocket:

http://www.nhatanh.net/blog/websocket-php-html5-tutorial-echo-server.html

Testando em uma máquina com sistema operacional Linux e servidor Apache funcionou corretamente na parte que foi realizada a inicialização do servidor com o comando `php server.php`, mostrando corretamente no Terminal as conexões realizadas e o socket com o chat funcionou corretamente exceto que a conexão logo era perdida depois de poucas envios de mensagem.

Porém, ao testar em uma máquina com Windows 8 e servidor IIS, ao executar o comando `php server.php` não ficou disponivel para o usuário verificar quais solicitações ao socket estavam sendo realizadas e o socket não funcionou ao se conectar, sempre retorna erro desconhecido mesmo com o WebSocket instalado e ativo nas configurações do IIS.

Como posso fazer para o projeto com WebSocket funcionar corretamente?

Ao clicar em Connect no arquivo `client.html` mesmo depois do comando para inicilizar o arquivo PHP:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:2207/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Como deveria mostrar no CMD ou Terminal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fica no CMD do Windows:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido.

No arquivo `php.ini` descomentei a seguinte linha:

```
;extension=php_sockets.dll
```

E reiniciei o servidor IIS e ao executar o script PHP o mesmo começou a executar.

Se você não possuir a DLL é possível baixar no seguinte site:

http://www.php.net/downloads.php

Espero que isso ajude mais desenvolvedores.